# What exactly is this Turn off the SSL certificate verification in Postman doing?

Tags: ssl, proxy, openssl, postman, ssl-certificate

Does turning off ssl certificate verification is not verifying the certificates at all. ?

I'm using one way ssl in one of the application. The application is currently using self signed certificate.
if I turn on the ssl certificate, the postman shows `SSL Error: Self signed certificate`.

To test the application, I'm currently sending request on https uri with turn off ssl feature. The request is being send and received correctly. However is this really a https connection ? And is this certificate getting verified at all ?

I'm bit confused that how is this https connection getting handled if ssl feature is off.

And what should be the procedure to be done in postman and ssl If I wish to test my https request with ssl.

Comment: In scenarios like this, your certificate is not being verified, but the communication channel is still encrypted, nonetheless.  The problem with running in this mode is that it makes the application (and potentially clients) susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks, where an attacker can present any certificate, and it won't be verified for trust, name, expiration, revoked status, etc.  In general, obtain a valid (non-self-signed) cert from a trusted root CA that both the application and clients trust, and use that.  HTH.

Comment: Thank a lot for info lee. I had one doubt that why am I even able to communicate if certificate is not getting verified. isn't the server only accepting ssl enabled requests only.

technically i shouldn't be allowed to communicate because my server accept only https requests and listen on port 443 only.